# Accessing Pi's files - help

Tags: software-development

I've invented a product and due to limited time and funds, paid someone else to use a Pi to construct a 'proof of concept' for me. It was eventually delivered, and my next move will be to install all the hardware into a suitable case to show it to potentially interested parties.

Just to clarify, the spec given to the dev was very specific. However, I cannot share it here because that would then mean the product is unprotectable from an IP perspective.

Unfortunately, despite paying what we agreed, I've found that some of the things originally specified have not been implemented. So, not having any more money I need to try to make those changes myself. I was supplied with an image file which I then put on an SD card. When the Pi boots it goes directly into what its supposed to do and (issues mentioned notwithstanding) works fine.

However, I need to understand a few things before I can try to make these changes so wonder if some kind person might help me to understand what I need to do to:

1. understand which cable is best to connect a 'proper' screen (currently it's only 3.5"!) (It's a Pi V3b BTW)
2. find the files I need and identify what files run when. I assume from there I'll work out which I need to edit.
3. understand how I can access said files from my PC? Do I need to? Thinking it best for back up purposes!

Sorry these are such seemingly daft questions, but I really have looked for what I think I need. I wonder if my problem is not knowing what I need?

Many thanks
David

Comment: Post a copy of your product brief and the documentation the developer supplied and some kind soul may help. If your product brief was as vague as this question …

Comment: Can you not get your developer to supply the code as a zip file?

Comment: I'm simply looking to understand how to get the files off the Pi at this point.
I cant share the spec as that would make it unprotectable from an IP perspective.
I have asked him to do that but he simply doesn't reply. All I have is an image file. Could I somehow break that down?

Comment: Pi to TV is HDMI.  Just look at the Pi suppliers detailed on the Foundations site (bottom of https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) Take the SD card out of the Pi and keep it safe - use an SD copy program to make a backup or three (I'm a Mac user but I've heard of https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/ - never tired it obviously) as for 2 and 3 - talk to the developer (and / or lawyer) there are lots of ways to start programs (even assuming it does) and locations the files could be in. You need a local developer with Linux skills not asking general questions.

Comment: Simplest place to locate the files would be in /home/pi or a sub-folder under there - but who knows. Where did you find this developer - i need to avoid it. Hope you didn't pay much.

Comment: Update. I've found out how to access the individual files which made up the .img  
I can see a number of .py files so I installed Thonny and can see how I can edit so have done.
I tried to edit the same files directly on the Pi but it will not let me save them! Any ideas peeps?

Comment: CoderMike. India - enough said?
I now suspect he sub contracted it out to someone else which is prob why he's not replied.
He couldn't even tell me which GPIO pins were used but now I've found that information in the program.
Part of this is the reading out of text. He's used Festival. 
I originally wanted to be able to play previously recorded MP3 or WAV files so the voice was human. IS there a way to do that 'simply'?

Comment: Andrew. Thank you. Cable ordered.

Comment: `it will not let me save them` could be an ownership/permission issue ... try using sudo ... of course, it could be that the setup of the image is such that the whole filesystem is readonly - you'll need to be very experienced with linux to know what the problem is